# Linqpad Can't connect to Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, dtd, linqpad

I am trying to create a LinqPad connection to a SharePoint Server's List Services. I have selected WCF Data Services 5.1 (OData 3) as the data context and http://sharepoint.host.com/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx as the URL

I get the following error: XmlException: For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method.

It doesn't matter if I use credentials or not.

What is the cause of this error? What is the soure of this error? I don't see how I can change the property in XmlReaderSettings. 
Is this a security configuration on the server? Is there a solution or workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Please try to connect to /_vti_bin/ListData.svc

Comment: Thank you! this should be definitely be marked as answered.